# Mongoose validation works for string but not for array of strings

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to validate a field in my Schema to check if the string passed has a valid extension and if it is from a whitelisted host
I'm using the [mongoose-validator](https://github.com/leepowellcouk/mongoose-validator) lib to create my rules.

The problem is, when the field is a String, it validates perfectly:

```
photos:  {type: String, 
          validate: [validate('isValidExtension'), validate('isValidHostname')]},
```

But what I really want is an Array of Strings:

```
photos: [{type: String, 
          validate: [validate('isValidExtension'), validate('isValidHostname')]}],
```

And, for some reason, it doesn't call the validation this way.

I have another example where I'm using a similar validation, but instead of using an Array of Strings, I'm using an Array of Objects.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes more sense for me to validate each of the Strings inside the array, but this is the way it works:

```
photos: {type: [String], 
          validate: [validate('isValidExtension'), validate('isValidHostname')]},
```